# Word press - JSPDF - Sending PDF as attachment from wp_mail - Special characters

Tags: php, ajax, html, wp-mail

This is my very first post. Thanks to all your answers on other posts.

Am using JSPDF to send an attachment through AJAX call to PHP server- A mail is sent from here with the generated PDF as attachment. I have been through many posts where they say other languages like Danish ( in this example ) needs to have a custom font.

But my question here is -> When i save the file using doc.save , it is completely fine. But when i send the data through AJAX call to PHP , the attachment has scrambled characters for the specific danish letters.

The HTML body displays the letters as well, but not the PDF attachment.

Has it something to do with the encoding ? that only attached PDF doesnt show the letters( front end saved PDF does show letters).

My HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<script>
    function sendmail() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
        var con1 = document.getElementById("dispID1");
        doc.fromHTML(con1, 10, 10);
        doc.save("file.pdf"); // This is to test from frontend if the PDF is saving
        var pdf = doc.output();
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data", pdf);
        var mailid = document.getElementById('mailadd').value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var mailresp = this.responseText;
                //  alert(mailresp);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "/sendmailattach.php?q=" + mailid, true);
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="dispID1">
        These are the danish characters å æ ø that needs be sent as PDF attachment
    </div>
    <div id="dispID2">

        <input type="text" style="width:auto;" id="mailadd" size="32" name="mailadd" maxlength="32" value="Indtast email-adresse">
        <br>

        <input type="submit" style=" width: auto;background-color: #eb5f1f;padding: 5px 5px;border: none;border-radius: 1px;cursor: pointer;text-transform: none;" value="Send" onclick="sendmail()">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP Code from server

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/wp-load.php';

if(!empty($_POST['data'])){

$data = $_POST['data'];
$filepath =  __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$filename = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."test.pdf";
    

file_put_contents($filename, $data);
$attachment = array($filename);
} else {
    $hint= "No Data Sent";
}

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$to = $q;
$subject = 'This email has attachment';

$body = "<html>
<body>
<p> These are the danish characters “å æ ø ” that needs be sent as PDF attachment-but appearing in email</p>
</body>
</html>";
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');



wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachment  );

unlink($filename); // Deletion of the created file.
echo $hint;

?>
```

The PDF File when saved at frontend has clear danish letters:
[image: PDF File when saved at front end]

The mail body: These are the danish characters "å æ ø " that needs be sent as PDF attachment-but appearing in email

The PDF file received as an attachment :
[image: PDF file received in mail as attachment]

Request if you could please help with this.

Comment: I'm a little confused is it the PDF attachment that has the issue, or the email body itself that has the issue? Have you tested that `test.pdf` is valid by not deleting it and downloading and inspecting manually? I it's already mangled before it's read in by `$data = $_POST['data'];` then no amount of WordPress knowledge can help you

Comment: Also be aware that the code in your question is wildly insecure as it would allow _anybody_ to send emails with PDF attachments to other people with no authentication or security. This would open your server up for sending spam and get your server blacklisted by email providers. You could even send hundreds of thousands of emails to someone with a simple terminal command just by visiting `/sendmailattach.php?q=youremail@example.com` repeatedly, and even attach malware. If this code is on a production server you should take it down ASAP to add some minimal login protections and validations

Comment: Also `“å æ ø ”` is not a valid HTML string, those characters need to be encoded. I would also strongly advise against adding standalone PHP files to handle AJAX requests for security reasons, you can avoid this by using either the legacy `admin-ajax.php` API, or REST API endpoints. REST API would allow you to make your AJAX requests to pretty URLs and WP functions would be available. It'll even do some things for you like checking login status etc